# typeerror jquery(...).isotope is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using a word press theme BuyShop into my word press website. this theme is working fine.

But if i am trying to use a word press plugin that i have created by my own then the theme is breaking and giving the following error:

```
typeerror jquery(...).isotope is not a function
```

This theme is using jquery 1.10 and my plugin is using 2.1.1. this error is generating at the time of embedding the jQuery into my plugin.

any idea how to solve this issue??? Please suggest some solution on my plugin side.

Best Regards,

Comment: Can I have look up in to your site /

Comment: Please give me url site

Comment: so u are using 2 versions of jquery..??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First check if all the necessary script are properly loaded.Incase u still get an error,it might be caused due to some conflicts or so.If you are using multiple versions of jQuery,try the following solution.

```
<!-- load jQuery 2.2.1 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery221 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.10 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery110 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Then use the appropriate version of the jquery variable to call the isotope plugin.Hope that gives u an idea mate.. :)